# How to extract geo location of city and plot the map

Tags: geography

I would like to construct Turkey's map using Geocoordinate of each city. This [link](https://pewat.blogspot.com/2017/12/turkiye-il-snrlar-koordinatlar-geojson.html) has  all coordinate of of cities but I don't know how to extract the data from website. I did manually two cities and it seems it is working.

```
hatay={{36.0616, 37.0235}, {36.2547, 37.0087}, {36.3472, 36.9553}, {36.4426,
   36.9533}, {36.6261, 36.841}, {36.6685, 36.8368}, {36.6786, 
  36.8185}, {36.6271, 36.7577}, {36.6369, 36.7051}, {36.588, 
  36.636}, {36.5999, 36.562}, {36.5529, 36.497}, {36.5891, 
  36.3978}, {36.6226, 36.3912}, {36.6277, 36.3542}, {36.6078, 
  36.3299}, {36.6662, 36.3302}, {36.6711, 36.3024}, {36.7003, 
  36.2922}, {36.7048, 36.2503}, {36.6184, 36.2166}, {36.5839, 
  36.2321}, {36.4954, 36.2345}, {36.4711, 36.2018}, {36.3975, 
  36.2232}, {36.4006, 36.1915}, {36.3767, 36.1694}, {36.3978, 
  36.0838}, {36.3786, 36.001}, {36.3442, 35.9924}, {36.3172, 
  36.0041}, {36.2979, 35.9917}, {36.3025, 35.9574}, {36.2127, 
  35.9515}, {36.1809, 35.9017}, {36.1831, 35.8356}, {36.1691, 
  35.8154}, {36.1164, 35.8655}, {36.0187, 35.8811}, {36.0229, 
  35.9245}, {36.0085, 35.9403}, {35.9358, 35.9187}, {35.9185, 
  35.9323}, {35.979, 36.019}, {35.8968, 36.1579}, {35.7804, 
  36.2988}, {35.781, 36.3224}, {35.816, 36.3604}, {35.8535, 
  36.369}, {35.8604, 36.3957}, {35.896, 36.4154}, {35.9096, 
  36.4451}, {35.9826, 36.4743}, {36.0368, 36.5337}, {36.1851, 
  36.7243}, {36.1888, 36.7232}, {36.1888, 36.7226}, {36.186, 
  36.7224}, {36.1851, 36.7243}, {36.1488, 36.5907}, {36.1946, 
  36.596}, {36.2157, 36.6593}, {36.1926, 36.7051}, {36.2021, 
  36.7271}, {36.1871, 36.729}, {36.206, 36.7824}, {36.1485, 
  36.8551}, {36.1296, 36.8532}, {36.1407, 36.8621}, {36.0857, 
  36.9051}, {36.0171, 36.9301}, {35.9376, 36.8865}, {35.9449, 
  36.8743}, {35.9457, 36.8643}, {35.9136, 36.8955}, {35.9542, 
  36.9637}, {36.0416, 37.0256}, {36.0616, 37.0235}};
osmaniye={{36.3279, 37.3484}, {36.4889, 37.3689}, {36.5828, 37.4052}, {36.651, 
  37.33}, {36.7286, 37.2761}, {36.5325, 37.1075}, {36.4426, 
  36.9533}, {36.3472, 36.9553}, {36.2547, 37.0087}, {36.0416, 
  37.0256}, {36.0594, 37.1239}, {36.001, 37.1742}, {35.8748, 
  37.1217}, {35.8528, 37.1287}, {35.9043, 37.2083}, {35.8818, 
  37.2416}, {35.8843, 37.3596}, {36.0233, 37.5623}, {36.1504, 
  37.6354}, {36.3024, 37.6512}, {36.2121, 37.5002}, {36.2463, 
  37.3709}, {36.3279, 37.3484}};

GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Black], GeoStyling[Red, Opacity[0.7]], 
  Polygon[hatay], GeoStyling[Green, Opacity[0.7]], Polygon[osmaniye]}]
```

[image]

Here is the [link](http://www.beycan.net/eklenen/turkiye/turkiye-iller.png) for city map of Turkey. Any suggestion.

**Edit**

After @C.E. suggestion I made this heat map for population of city of Turkey. This is so cool.

```
population=Log@{2.21648*10^6, 615076., 715693., 536285., 402404., 329888., 
 5.44503*10^6, 2.3644*10^6, 97096., 166143., 1.08084*10^6, 
 1.20482*10^6, 193577., 585252., 80417., 221693., 273354., 341474., \
303184., 264779., 2.9368*10^6, 530417., 186074., 528422., 
 1.01874*10^6,      1.6999*10^6, 377610., 406855., 583671., 231511., 760476., 860620.,      2.00552*10^6, 437393., 170173., 275761., 
 1.57523*10^6, 194775., 433830., 1.50292*10^7, 4.27968*10^6, 
 1.12762*10^6, 244453., 246672., 287654., 372373., 
 1.37672*10^6, 136319., 278749., 356050., 234529., 1.88327*10^6, 
 2.18015*10^6, 572256., 786676., 1.41304*10^6, 809719., 
 1.79393*10^6, 938751., 404544., 292365., 352727., 742341., 527724., \
331041., 990214., 1.31299*10^6,      1.98575*10^6, 324394., 207427., 503236., 621301.,      1.00546*10^6, 602086., 786326., 82498., 364971., 
 1.10689*10^6, 251203., 418650., 596892.};



  minMax = MinMax[population];
vec = {{0, 0, 165}, {40, 50, 220}, {90, 120, 240}, {140, 180, 
    247}, {195, 223, 240}, {230, 227, 230}, {240, 223, 195}, {247, 
    180, 140}, {240, 120, 90}, {220, 50, 40}, {164, 0, 0}};
colAll = Blend[RGBColor @@@ (vec/255), Rescale[#, minMax]] &;
colors = colAll[#] & /@ population;
regions = 
  Entity["Country", "Turkey"][
   EntityProperty["Country", "AdministrativeDivisions"]];
names = StringTrim[#, ", Turkey"] & /@ 
   EntityValue[regions, 
    EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", "Name"]];
labelCoordinates = 
  Reverse /@ 
   EntityValue[regions, 
    EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", "Coordinates"]];
polygons = 
  EntityValue[regions, 
   EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", "Polygon"]];


Legended[Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], Riffle[colors, polygons], 
   MapThread[Text, {names, labelCoordinates}]}, ImageSize -> 1000], 
 Placed[BarLegend[{colAll, minMax}, LegendLayout -> "Row", 
   LegendMarkerSize -> {800, 25}], Bottom]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The data is built into Mathematica, so we can use the entity system to do this.

```
regions = Entity["Country", "Turkey"][EntityProperty["Country", "AdministrativeDivisions"]];
names = StringTrim[#, ", Turkey"] & /@ EntityValue[regions, EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", "Name"]];
labelCoordinates = Reverse /@ EntityValue[regions, EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", "Coordinates"]];
polygons = EntityValue[regions, EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", "Polygon"]];
colors = ColorData[97, #] & /@ Range[Length[regions]];

Graphics[{
  Riffle[colors, polygons],
  MapThread[Text, {names, labelCoordinates}]
  }, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also use `GeoGraphics` to get a different type of visualization of this map. One problem is that there are more regions on this map than there are distinct colors in the color scheme `ColorData[97]`, which means that several regions have the same colors. Some of the regions neighbor each other, unfortunately, which means that we can't tell where the border is.

Comment: I used this for border. Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black],......]

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci Good, that will do it.

Comment: This is awesome!! I do know that each city has location coordinate, but I did not know Mathematica has coordinate of each city along the border.

Comment: One question though how `Graphics[]` understand alignment of each polygon so that they fit perfectly? I understand how `GeoGraphics[] ` plot the ploygon based on gps location.

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci What we get is a list of latitude and longitude values. You can consider latitude to be the x coordinate and longitude to be the y values. The regions will fit perfectly with each other because the longitudes and latitudes on their shared borders are the same for both regions. One difference between `Graphics` and `GeoGraphics` is that `GeoGraphics` can do different projections (as we know, there is more than one way to plot the spherical surface of the earth in two dimensions.)

Comment: One more question. Each city has subregion. Can we scrap  coordinate of subregion if  Mathematica has the data? Here is for one city called Gaziantep http://www.nenedirvikipedi.com/cografya/gaziantep-ilinin-ilceleri-ve-gaziantep-ilcelerinin-nufuslari-10866.html#&gid=1&pid=1

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci Finding out what data Mathematica has is an experimental endeavor. In this case, what I do is that I take one of the region entities and check the "Properties" property. I then get a list of the properties that entity has. In this case, I see that it has a subdivisions property for example. Try `Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Adana", "Turkey"}][
 EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", "Subdivisions"]]`, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes this are subregion of city of Adana. I would like to plot  second map like here https://www.avvg.org.tr/yazilar/156-turkiye-ilceler-haritasi-verileri.html

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci You should have everything you need to do that in my answer. Create a list with all the subdivision entities in it and plot them just like I plotted the larger regions.

Comment: I guess Mathematica does not have data for subregion because this does not work. `labelCoordinates = 
 Reverse /@ 
  EntityValue[regions, 
   EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", "Subdivisions", 
    "Coordinates"]]`

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci ah, you're right. That's disappointing. Mathematica does not have polygons for subregions.

Answer (score 1):

```
TurkeyCityList = CityData[{All, "Turkey"}];

CityData[#, "Coordinates"] & /@ TurkeyCityList
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP is saying that he wants to create [this](http://www.beycan.net/eklenen/turkiye/turkiye-iller.png) type of map, which means you need to get the boundary for each region, not just a single coordinate.

Comment: How do you know *which* cities are to be grouped to define a "region"?

Comment: See my answer, we can see that what is thought of in Turkey as cities is what Mathematica considers administrative regions. These have well-defined borders.

Comment: But I see no reason that the regions *Mathematica* assumes are the ones the OP wants.  He doesn't state it as such.

Comment: I compared them with the map OP provided and the names are the same, the regions are the same. (It can be a bit difficult to tell because the plot reuses colors, and colors of neighboring regions can have the same color. But I randomized the colors and evaluated several times to check.)

Comment: It would have been far simpler for all if the OP had merely asked:  "How do I plot a map of Turkey showing its governmental regions?" and avoided all this intermediate work on cities and such.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork sorry about if my question is not clear. I will edit it accordingly. Thanks.